# How to change raster values of a specific area on the map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a raster file of a country surrounded by sea. I want the value, of the pixels that are above the sea (outside of the land), to be zero and everything else (pixels in the land) to have the initial value when i imported the raster file.
In the beginning every pixel has a random value (both, these on the land and on the sea). But I just want to zero all the values of the pixels on the sea

[image]

Comment: ok it is not exactly random. I have a country with vs30 velocities as the values of the pixels on the land and the values of the pixels on the sea are 600 like in the image. And i want to zero all the values of the pixels that are on the sea (600-->0). I use the pixel inspector to show you the values. Thanks for the response!!

Comment: The problem is that some of the values on the land are above and some below 600 and some are equal to 600. So i can't use raster calculator to zero the values below or above 600.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend finding country boundary data and then clip out areas of your raster using [Clip](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm) or [Extract by Mask](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm).

Alternatively, you can convert your country boundaries to raster and use [Con](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) to convert values outside of your features of interest to 0 or NoData.

You can find accurate country boundary data from [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/).